# Getting an element by its CSS class name starting with a dot

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had to rename a CSS class that used to start with a `#` sign to a dot so it could be handled by the `ExtJS` framework properly.

That jQuery script used to work fine until I made that change, now it whines it cannot find the element.

I'm not very used to jQuery, my question is is this supposed to work?

```
$('.x-panel-body-cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){

    //some code that errors out because .x-panel-body-cssmenu can't be found apparently...

});
```

This is the HTML in question:

```
<div class="x-panel x-border-item x-box-item x-panel-cssmenu" style="height: 441px; right: auto; left: 0px; top: 100px; margin: 0px; width: 200px;" id="navigationmenu-1011">
    <div id="navigationmenu-1011-body" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-cssmenu x-layout-fit x-panel-body-cssmenu" style="height: 441px; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 200px;">            
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><span>Home</span></a></li>
            <li class="has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Eligibility list</span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>View/manage list</span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><span>Add employee</span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"><span>Cases</span></a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#"><span>Documents</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS (`.x-panel-body-cssmenu` used to be called `#cssmenu`:

```
.x-panel-body-cssmenu,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul li,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-right: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background: #36aae7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #1fa0e4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
.holder {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.holder::after,
.holder::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.holder::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover > span::after,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li.active > a > span::after,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li.open > a > span::after {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}
.holder::before {
  top: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-left-color: inherit;
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #49505a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul ul li.open > a,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  background: #424852;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:last-child > a,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > a,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last.open > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 11.5px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul ul li.active > a::after,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul ul li.open > a::after,
.x-panel-body-cssmenu ul ul li > a:hover::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

I tried escaping the dot, no dot, using a pound sign anyways, no go.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Everything looks ok from the jQuery end, probably something to do with the name or the HTML.

Comment: you really need better class names if you moved from an id prefix (#) to a class prefix (.)...

Comment: That code won't error out. The selector simply won't match any elements, so it won't bind the event handler to anything, so the function will never run.

Comment: I think that the id of your element is 'x-panel-body-cssmenu'. This is why, you had '#' sign in your CSS file. If you change your CSS from '#x-panel-body-cssmenu' to '.x-panel-body-cssmenu', you have to add to your HTML element class="x-panel-body-cssmenu".

Comment: @dandavis ExtJS apparently needs them formatted as such.

Comment: How does the html look that refers to x-panel-body-cssmenu?

Comment: @FrancisDucharme:  i could find nothing from extjs documenting, confirming, or even suggesting that. i think you might not need such an elaborate workaround after all: it's all just regular CSS selectors...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you "renamed". Please show your before and after HTML or CSS.

Comment: Now you've edited the code to show the HTML… your original question is highly misleading (the class name includes neither `.` nor `#`) and the code you have should select the element and bind the function to it.

Comment: @Quentin I think that jQuery code would look for an element who's ID was `#cssmenu` but since I've change the CSS to a CLASS name (`.x-panel-body-cssmenu`), it's not picking it up anymore.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme See my answer below.

Comment: @morgul Sorry, that was not the problem, I made a typo in my question. It's fixed now.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme It works in my jsfiddle([link](http://jsfiddle.net/L9G2M/)) if you click on "Eligibility list" using exactly the code you post above. So i'm not sure to understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NB: This answers the original question. The question has been since edited to show code with which there doesn't appear to be any problem at all.

---

In general, you should avoid using special characters in class names at all. They are more trouble then they are worth.

However, if you are stuck with a class name containing a special character, you can escape it.

You also have an additional problem is that you need to prefix the class name with a `.` in a selector to indicate that you are using a class selector:

In your selector:

```
.\.x-panel-body-cssmenu
```

Note that since you are putting your selector in a JavaScript string literal, and `\` is a special character there, you need to escape the `\`

```
".\\.x-panel-body-cssmenu"
```

NB: [There is no such thing as a CSS class](http://pumpula.net/p/apps/css-vocabulary/). HTML has classes, CSS has class selectors.

Comment: Doesnt he need a starting dot to tell jQuery to look for a class? Ie:`$(".\\.x-panel-body-cssmenu")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Turns out the problem was complicated by element ID manipulation by the ExtJS framework and also the (document).ready event was firing before the element I'm trying to work on was actually rendered (again, the ExtJS viewport must be interfering with jQuery's usual behaviour).